# eslint rule to disallow specific variables / methods

Tags: javascript, eslint

I need an eslint rule to disallow the usage of a specific variable / method. In particular, I don't want anyone to use `Array.from` in our project.

I've looked into http://eslint.org/docs/rules/ and searched for custom rules, however, I'm not sure if this is even how rules work. It seems to me that rules are either turned on or off, not configured like “disallow usage of x, x.y and z()”

Is the way to go to write a [custom rule](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins)?

Comment: why don't you want them to use that?

Comment: We don't want to include the whole `babel-polyfill` package, since we use `Array.from` only one time. Older browsers don't support it, but we have lodash anyway included, so we prefer to use that. To prevent future errors, eslint should help us avoiding Array.from

Comment: are you using anything that returns an iterator such as Map or Set?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Old Androids just do not have the property `from` of `Array`.

Comment: if you are using a `Map` or `Set` types, those have functions that return iterators.

Comment: `Array.from` was previously just used to generate a list `[1..12]`, that was used for a datepicker in an angular application. I've replaced that particular part by hardcoding an array from 1 to 12, we don't need `Array.from` otherwise. Thats why we would like to prevent further usage of `Array.from` if there is no good reason for it. I still don't understand how that relates to `Map` / `Set`, sorry.

Comment: @wegenerd Seems like you don't understand what `Array.from` actually achieves. If you research it, maybe you won't want to disable its usage because it's going to be *very* useful when writing ES6. Anyway...https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-disallow-methods might help

Comment: I think this is a good question, regardless of whether OP should / shouldn't use `Array.from`. **It definitely [does not deserve downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/504611)**. As for why I specifically like this question: I find myself in a situation where I've had to extend a third-party library (Highcharts), but the extension precludes the use of another one of the library's functions. Naturally, I want others to be avoid using that function, and if they really do need it, to fix the extension code first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forbid a specific named function with ESlint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977713/how-to-forbid-a-specific-named-function-with-eslint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the rule doesn't exists in the core distribution, your best bet is to create a custom rule. You can also make it configurable by using `context.options` property inside of the rule, you can get configuration information.