# Eslint custom rule - Is it possible to find a variable value defined in ember component?

Tags: eslint, ember-cli, abstract-syntax-tree, eslintrc

For example, I want to restrict a specific class name usage across my product.

So, I had blocked that class name usage from .hbs files as template lint rules.

But, that classnames are being used as component **classname** variables.

So, Is this possible to get this specific component variable defined value and verify it?

I had checked all existing eslint rules to check whether any rule works as this.
But, I couldn’t find one.
If anyone know any existing rule works as my case please share that rule name also.

Any help would to appreciated!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977713/how-to-forbid-a-specific-named-function-with-eslint

Comment: no-restricted-syntax might be helpful here