# Disallow calling number.isNan on non-numbers using e.g. an eslint rule?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I just ran into a bug that was caused by evaluating `Number.isNan(someStringVariable)` instead of `Number.isNan(Number(someStringVariable))`. And then after searching this codebase, found a few other instances where `Number.isNan` was incorrectly called directly on a variable without converting it to a number first.

`Number.isNan` accepts an input of type `unknown`, but at least in this codebase, there is no reason to ever call `Number.isNan` on a variable that is not a number type, and any time someone does this, it's definitely a bug.

Does anyone know of a way to disallow this? I'm hoping there's an eslint rule that would let me achieve this. I didn't find an eslint rule that directly addresses this issue, but maybe there's a more generic one that I could add some custom configuration to?

I'm open to non-eslint methods of solving this problem too, as long as it doesn't break anything if one of our npm dependencies calls `Number.isNan` in this way.

EDIT: One possibility is to create my own isNaN function with better types, and use a custom config with the [no-restricted-syntax rule to ban the use of Number.isNan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65205076/5602521) with something like:

```
{
  rules: {
    'no-restricted-syntax': [
      'error',
      {
        message: "This is bug-prone, use MyCustomImpl.isNan instead",
        selector:
          'Number > Identifier[name="isNaN"]'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but I'd like to avoid this if possible, because we use the airbnb lint rules, which already include a `no-restricted-syntax` config, and I don't want to have to overwrite their rule. Also, if I do go with the approach of creating a wrapper isNaN function with better typing, it'd be nice to use an eslint rule that will automatically replace uses of `Number.isNaN` with the new custom `isNaN` when running `eslint --fix`

Comment: Trivia: This was implemented in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24436

Comment: I made a TypeScript feature request relating to this here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55878